# I have created a download link. But the downloaded file is missing its filetype (A plain file is downloaded every time)

Tags: c#, hyperlink, download

```
protected void downloadbtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Name, Data, Type from demons where ID=@Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                contentType = sdr["Type"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

//The filetype is not sent along with the file
// for e.g if  a photo is to be downloaded , then a plain file would be downloaded then you need to open it specificaly with paint or photos app

Comment: What do you mean by the "type is missing"? What is the content of the `contentType` variable?

Comment: it asks "save as type=All files" rather than .JPEG or .MP4 or .txt

Comment: OK that's the first question, and the second?

Comment: only a single question.

Comment: I asked 2 questions, please spend some time reading if you expect people to help you.

Comment: i think i'm unable to explain the question. sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that what is stored in the contentType variable is not a valid MIME type.

You can check out a list of known windows MIME types here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775147(v=vs.85)